# Embed Derby DB with Netbeans Platform Application - Module

Tags: java, netbeans, jdbc, derby, netbeans-7.4

I developed a project in Netbeans Platform Application i.e. like Modules.

When i run my project from Netbeans 7.4, it works fine and doesn't show any DB exception.

Now i created a installer using Netbeans 7.4 for my project. wen i install it, the DB is also installed but its not recognizing the DB and my connection url is `public final static String connectionURL = "jdbc:derby:ProjectDB;create=true;user=user;password=p@ssword";`.

When i copy paste the DB alone in a location eg: " d:\project DB " and change the code as `connectionURL = "jdbc:derby:D:\\project DB; create=true; user=user; password=p@ss"` it works fine. But i need to create along with the installer or want my project to recognize the DB.

When i searched i got the below links

https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/70/nbm-crud.html

https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-crud.html

but dint get a solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "its not recognizing the DB"? Did you write some code? Did it get an exception? What code did you write? What exception did you get?

Comment: @Bryan Pendleton I did this project in Netbeans platform application. So when i build the project i wont get a JAR to execute. I have to create a installer, when i install the project and launch it.. the project window opens but doesnt recognize the DB. I get thz exception `ERROR 42Y07: Schema 'DBUSER' does not exist`

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell from your description, but could you be seeing [this default schema with Netbeans issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21418694/netbeans-7-4-creating-entity-classes-jpa-from-java-db-embedded-database/22536023#22536023) ?

Answer (score 0):

Found the Solution..

- launh or run the project after doing clean Build from the "dist" folder.
- The new Database will be created in the "dist/project name" and you will get a error "Schema DB doesnt exists".
- Now close the application and delete the DB in the "dist/project name" folder and copy-paste the DB(this i did for Derby Database)  which you use for your project. And run the application agaiin.